# Data labels disappear after I reopen worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a worksheet with a scatter chart. On the data series, I added some data labels.
I defined the data series x and y ranges to some cells.
Since I use this worksheet as a template, the x and y ranges cells are empty.

Now my problem is: When I save and reopen the worksheet, then add some data in the x,y ranges cells, the data labels won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a NAME to the data series of the scatter chart. Initialy, I had only set the X and Y ranges without setting a name, which caused the problem.